# How to open .avsc file on macbook

Tags: macos, file, format, schema, avro

I have a file that is avro schema (.avsc file extension)
How can I open this file on my Macbook? I have no knowledge of this file format as I am using this for the first time.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

avsc files contain schema that is very much similar to json schemas. You can open it using any text editor like sublime, notepad++ (But sorry I don't know if they are for MacBook. But you can use any text editor supported on Macbook)